# Editing query to include math

Tags: sql

```
SELECT type, count(*) as Total 
    FROM table 
WHERE date between ((YEAR(CURDATE())-1900)*1000+DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())-30) 
   AND (YEAR(CURDATE())-1900)*1000+DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) 
   AND rp=100 
   AND pd in ('P7','P9','QU','QL') 
GROUP BY type;
```

This produces:

```
**TYPE**       **TOTAL**
   A               2
   B               4
```

Is it feasible to edit my query to give me a percentage like A/(A+B). I'm struggling to get A single types total value as the numerator, and the total value of all types as the denominator

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple version, a cte using a sub-query returning the table's total number of rows:

```
with cte as
(
    select type
    from table 
    where date between ((year(CURDATE())-1900)*1000+DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())-30) 
                    and (year(CURDATE())-1900)*1000+DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) 
      and rp = 100 
      and pd in ('P7', 'P9', 'QU', 'QL') 
)
select type, count(*), 100.0 * count(*) / (select count(*) from cte)
from cte
group by type
```

Comment: All of these answers are great but I went with cte. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Most straightforward and simple is:

```
select type
    , count(*) / (
          select count(*)
          from table 
          where date between ((year(CURDATE())-1900)*1000+DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())-30) 
           and (year(CURDATE())-1900)*1000+DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) 
           and rp=100 
           and pd in ('P7','P9','QU','QL') 
      ) as TotalFraction 
from table 
where date between ((year(CURDATE())-1900)*1000+DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())-30) 
and (year(CURDATE())-1900)*1000+DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) 
and rp=100 
and pd in ('P7','P9','QU','QL') 
group by type;
```

though you might want to make use of CTE or temporary table to avoid conditions repetition.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like the following, I guess you will need to do some altering depending on your data

```
select sum(case when type = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) /
      (sum(case when type = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) + sum(case when type = 'B' then 1 else 0 end)) as Ratio 
from table 
where date between ((year(CURDATE())-1900)*1000+DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())-30) 
and (year(CURDATE())-1900)*1000+DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) 
and rp=100 
and pd in ('P7','P9','QU','QL') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT type, Total, CONVERT(decimal, Total)/SUM(Total) OVER() AS Percentage
FROM
(
SELECT type, count(*) as Total 
    FROM table 
WHERE date between ((YEAR(CURDATE())-1900)*1000+DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())-30) 
   AND (YEAR(CURDATE())-1900)*1000+DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) 
   AND rp=100 
   AND pd in ('P7','P9','QU','QL') 
GROUP BY type
) TYPES
```